# How can I put a left not-fixed div on my webpage which height it is the maximum height it could be?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div on the left side of my webpage that has not to be **fixed** and has to be 100% of the height and 30% width. I mean, that if you scroll, it will be scrolled also and it will not be fixed in the same position all the time.

The problem that I am having it is that when I put `height: 100%;` it does not cover the height that I am indicating to him. It only covers the full height when I set `position:fixed` but never when I set it to `static`, `absolute` or `relative`.

What I though it is that it could be that I had to set `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` to the `<html>` tag but it does not seem to have any difference if I compare it with `<body>` tag (I know there are differences between both tags but I do not know if in this case they will be aplied, I think no).

Here is my `html` code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a prove</h1>
    <div id="proveDiv">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `CSS` code:

```
html{
  /* position: relative;  I comment these lines because I saw that there are not any effect
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
}

body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#proveDiv{
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q7x0rf4b/1/) is the fiddle in which you can see the effect. Just try to change the `position` attribute on `proveDiv` id css and you will se what I refer to.

I am stuck here and I cannot find any solution by myself or in SO. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/q7x0rf4b/5/ ??

Comment: @Pugazh It seems to be fixed as well.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle check this https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/q7x0rf4b/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the min-height of the div to view-port height like `min-height: 100vh;`. **[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/q7x0rf4b/7/)**

```
#proveDiv {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tell me about `vh`. I did not know that it exists but I am going to looking for now what does it really means. Thank you for the "trick"!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this is the working demo that I came up with.

http://codepen.io/BenCodeZen/pen/JXLbjN

The solution is based on a `display: flex;` on a parent container and defining the height of the element using `height: 100vh;` instead of 100%. By using flexbox, it will allow you more control over the layout for responsive design.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: But in your fiddle it does not cover the full height. Only wraps the `<h1>` tag.

Comment: Hm.. I wonder if an old version saved over accidentally. Nonetheless, it looks like you got the key point of using `vh` (which stands for viewport height) in order to allow the element to stretch the remaining height of the device.

Comment: Thanks for update your answer! Yes, the key was the `vh`. +1 because I like how you use it mixing with flex.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is because, when you use the attribute `fixed`, for some reason, the div's height will increase because it's inherited by default from its container. In this case, when your div is fixed and its height is set to 100%, the div takes the full height of its container which is the body.
PS: In case you want the div to have its initial height, you can use `position:initial`.

On the other side, using position:relative is your best option.
By default, the div will have its own initial height which depends on its content. When you have more text inside your div, it will automatically increase its height.

To solve your problem, use a relative position and set the height as you want. (100% will make the div take the height of the body)
Note that it is important that you set both the body & html tag's height otherwise it won't work. (If you need further explaination, just comment below)

This is how your CSS should be:

```
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#proveDiv{
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you have any questions, comment below.

Comment: Nice explanation but I still does not understand why if I put before both `html` and `body` tags with 100% `height` and `width` it did not work. I had `html` tag as `relative` and `body` tag as `absolute` in a first instance.

Comment: You'll never have to set the position of your `html` or `body` tags on your page. It's pointless since the `html` element represents the whole page, so you can't set the position of the whole page unless you're thinking about positioning the browser window itself, but it's not going to work anyway. Same goes for the body tag, you don't need to position it. Since it will contain the whole `html` code of your page, moving it is pointless.

Comment: The difference between the `html` and `body` tags is that `html` tags represent the whole page and everything that it contains, including `javascript` code or `CSS` code, while the `body` tag can only contain `html` code.

Comment: Then, if the `html` element represents the whole page. Why do you have to set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`? If it represents the whole page it should be that it will be already at 100% of both properties. Isn't it?

Comment: default and 100% isn't necessarily the same. If you want to use `height:100%` on an element, its parent element should also have a set height. To explain, when you use the 100% height attribute, the browser will attempt to set the element's height depending on its parent's height, so it will check the height of the parent element, and by that I mean that the browser will look for the height property of the parent element. This is why you should always set the parent element's height before setting the child's height using a percentage value.

Comment: The solution that was given to you by @Pugazh makes the height take 100% of the viewport and not of the parent element. See viewport units here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp.
This is why people need to provide explainations along with their answer. Understanding the problem is much better than simply getting the solution.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong please but then, the fact that the `html` tag represents the whole page does not mean that the `height` and the `width` are set to 100%, just that it represents all the content inside the page. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. `<html>` tag is just a container for all the website elements including html code that is contained inside the `<body>` tags or the javascript code that is contained inside the `<script>` tags and of course the CSS code contained inside the `<style>` tags. Nevertheless, they are still tags and are interpreted by browsers as elements, but it just doesn't make sure to position them.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for clarify me that. I learn a lot with you. +1 for this nice explanation ;)